# Windows 8 guest account

Tags: windows-8, guest-account

Is there any way to restrict a guest account on windows 8 from being able to download things like movies, music, etc? I have a roommate who insists on downloading things on my guest account and I want to be able to disable it. I'm no techie by any means so something simple would be the way to go for me. Thanks!

Comment: Disable the guest account and tell him to get his own computer.

Comment: I agree with @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007. It's the simplest and cleanest solution although it won't do much for your popularity.

Comment: He's leaving soon anyways, and the others in the house don't do the things he does. I'd just prefer the last few days to be peaceful. Taking the computer away wont make it peaceful. I don't care if he surfs, but don't want him downloading crap. I will try what has been suggested, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable the guest account and create one standard user, so that your roommate can use it as guest account. To restrict any application on the standard user, go to control panel `control panel -> Manage another account -> Set up Parental Controls`. Now select the newly created user and enable the option `On enforcing current settings -> Allow and block specific programs -> test can only use the programs I allow`, here you can restrict any specific program like download manager, any browser, media player....

Comment: Yup - if he's going to act like a child, treat him like a child. +1.

Comment: Thanks so much, I will definitely be doing this. I have the laptop in my room right now, but he's asked to use it to watch one of the shows I download. He got my password and he's been using my account. I want to change my password, move the folder to the guess account (so he can't use mine anymore) and restrict downloading. As has been said, he can get his own damned computer if he can't respect the rules around my computer.